# How can I move a generic TS argument definition without getting the "Property doesn't exist on type 'unknown'" error?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm confused as to why the definitions of `doSomething1()` and `doSomething2()` are not treated equally?

```
class Example<
    TypeA = void,
    TypeB = void,
    ArgsType = { valueA?:TypeA, valueB?:TypeB }
> {
    valueA?:TypeA;
    valueB?:TypeB;
    
    constructor( valueA:TypeA, valueB:TypeB ) {
        this.valueA = valueA;
        this.valueB = valueB;
    }
    
    doSomething1( args: { valueA?:TypeA, valueB?:TypeB } ) {
        // this works
        const { valueA, valueB } = args;
        
        console.log( valueA );
        console.log( valueB );
    }
    
    doSomething2( args: ArgsType ) {
        // this throws "Property 'valueA' does not exist on type 'unknown'"
        const { valueA, valueB } = args;
        
        console.log( valueA );
        console.log( valueB );
    }
    
}
```

If I define all the parameters manually (seen in `doSomething1()`), the code works as expected. If I try to stay DRY and move it next to where `TypeA` and `TypeB` are defined, creating a new generic type for the arguments, I get a `Property 'valueA' does not exist on type 'unknown'`.

It seems to be related to the `TypeA` and `TypeB` generics being optional, but that's still the case when I'm using them manually, so what's happening here?

How can I define `ArgsType` derived from optional generics and re-use it in my method definitions?

Comment: `ArgsType` just *defaults* to `{ valueA?:TypeA, valueB?:TypeB }`, but it could be anything at all.  You shouldn't use a default type argument for that purpose.  You'll need to define `ArgsType` elsewhere and refer to it.  Unfortunately you can't do so inside the class (see [ms/TS#7061](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061) for the relevant feature request) so you'll need it outside and generic, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8VqMm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thomas was a bit faster, but yes, I agree that it's annoying it can't be defined inside the class body as a derived generic. Thank you for the help regardless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic behind this one is that you can have `{valueA: TypeA, valueB: TypeB}` in ArgsType, but you could also have `{whatever: 999, somethingElse: "Hello"}` instead.

The compiler is right.

To define it you could do:

```
interface ArgsType<A, B> {
  valueA: A;
  valueB: B;
}

class Example<TypeA = void, TypeB = void, T extends ArgsType<TypeA, TypeB> = ArgsType<TypeA, TypeB>> {

  valueA: TypeA;
  valueB: TypeB;

  constructor(a: TypeA, b: TypeB) {
    this.valueA = a;
    this.valueB = b;
  }

  doSomething1(args: {valueA?: TypeA, valueB?: TypeB}) {
    const { valueA, valueB } = args;
    
    console.log( valueA );
    console.log( valueB );
  }

  doSomething2(args: T) { // T extends ArgsType<TypeA, TypeB>
    const { valueA, valueB } = args;
    
    console.log( valueA );
    console.log( valueB );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was going to be my fallback. Annoying that it can't be defined inside the class body as a "non-optional" parameter, but this should work at least :) Ty